# After moving Spring Boot to 2.7.0 version, clients (iOS and Android) stopped receiving messages through websockets

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I updated Spring Boot from 2.1.5.RELEASE to 2.7.0 and after that mobile application on iOS and Android stoped recieving the messages through websockets. I believe some aditional configs should be added. Bellow is my code

WebSocketConfig.java

```
package com.belcowallet.ws;

import com.belcowallet.security.core.CoreTokenProvider;
import com.belcowallet.service.CoinService;
import com.belcowallet.service.UserService;
import com.belcowallet.util.Constants;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketTransportRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    private final CoreTokenProvider coreTokenProvider;
    private final MessageChannel clientOutboundChannel;
    private final CoinService coinService;
    private final UserService userService;

    public WebSocketConfig(CoreTokenProvider coreTokenProvider, @Lazy @Qualifier("clientOutboundChannel") MessageChannel clientOutboundChannel, @Lazy CoinService coinService, @Lazy UserService userService) {
        this.coreTokenProvider = coreTokenProvider;
        this.clientOutboundChannel = clientOutboundChannel;
        this.coinService = coinService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/v1/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                    if (accessor.getNativeHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER) != null) {
                        List<String> authorization = accessor.getNativeHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
                        if (authorization.size() > 0 && authorization.get(0).split(" ").length > 1) {
                            String accessToken = authorization.get(0).split(" ")[1];
                            if (coreTokenProvider.validateToken(accessToken)) {
                                Authentication authentication = coreTokenProvider.getAuthentication(accessToken);
                                if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                                }
                                accessor.setUser(authentication);
                                System.out.println(" %%%% CONNECT, phone: " + authentication.getName());
                            } else {
                                StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR);
                                headerAccessor.setMessage("Access is denied");
                                headerAccessor.setSessionId(accessor.getSessionId());
                                clientOutboundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                    String destination = accessor.getDestination();
                    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                    String phone = authentication == null ? accessor.getUser().getName() : authentication.getName();
                    System.out.println(" %%%% SUBSCRIBE, phone: " + phone + ", destination: " + destination);

                    if (destination.equals("/user/queue/balance")) {
                        coinService.pushBalance(userService.findByPhone(phone).getId(), null);
                    }
                } else if (StompCommand.DISCONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand()) || StompCommand.UNSUBSCRIBE.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                    String phone = authentication == null ? accessor.getUser().getName() : authentication.getName();

                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(phone) && "anonymous".equalsIgnoreCase(phone)) {
                        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR);
                        headerAccessor.setMessage("Access is denied");
                        headerAccessor.setSessionId(accessor.getSessionId());
                        clientOutboundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders()));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(" %%%% DISCONNECT, phone: " + phone);
                    }
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
        registry.addDecoratorFactory(webSocketHandler -> new WebSocketSessionHandlerDecorator(webSocketHandler));
    }

    private class WebSocketSessionHandlerDecorator extends WebSocketHandlerDecorator {
        public WebSocketSessionHandlerDecorator(WebSocketHandler delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                super.handleMessage(session, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WebSocketSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.belcowallet.ws;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import static org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageType.*;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpTypeMatchers(CONNECT, UNSUBSCRIBE, DISCONNECT, OTHER).permitAll();
        messages.simpTypeMatchers(SUBSCRIBE).authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>2.7.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <io.grpc.version>1.40.1</io.grpc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>7.54.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madgag.spongycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.54.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>${io.grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${io.grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${io.grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.binance.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>binance-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/binance-api-client-1.0.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.binance.dex.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>binance-dex-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/binance-dex-api-client-1.1.2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trustwallet</groupId>
            <artifactId>wallet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.11</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/wallet-core-2.6.11.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ciphertrace</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/grpc-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitcoinj</groupId>
            <artifactId>bitcoinj-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trulioo</groupId>
            <artifactId>normalizedapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.plaid</groupId>
            <artifactId>plaid-java</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>backend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is there someone faced the same issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I changed my subscribe name to `/user/${sessionId}/queue`. This solved the issue.